# Prevent dlopen'd library from overriding symbols

Tags: shared-libraries, dlopen

I know there's the RTLD_LOCAL flag which prevents symbols from the loaded library to enter the global scope. But the problem is there's no way to prevent the loaded library to then call dlopen with RTLD_GLOBAL, thus inserting symbols to the global scope.

Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: If you really need that level of isolation you may want to consider using a WebAssembly-based plugin system.

Answer (score 1):

> But the problem is there's no way to prevent the loaded library to then call dlopen with RTLD_GLOBAL, thus inserting symbols to the global scope.

A library that runs code *in your process* can do a million things: it could corrupt your heap, patch your executable text, override your already resolved and not yet unresolved `GOT` entries, redirect your open file descriptors to different files or sockets, etc. etc.

Worrying that it might `dlopen` something is a bit pointless. If you really want to isolate it from your process, run it in a different process.

But if for some reason you *only* care about `dlopen` and nothing else this library could do, you could find that library's `dlopen` `GOT` entry, and set it to `my_dlopen`, which either always returns `NULL`, or clears the `RTLD_GLOBAL` bit before calling the real `dlopen`.